# QTP : Ready state property not working for chrome

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

My application is very slow, it takes lots of loading time. How can i synchronize code with the  browser speed.
When i use 
**Browser("PACE").Object.readyState**
It is throwing error saying 
**Object doesn't support this action**

Any solutions???/

Comment: AFAIK `readyState` is relevant to `Page` not `Browser`.

Comment: You can always run a loop and keep checking for particular object exists or not, if exists come out of loop, otherwise keep running the loop and wait in between.